Finding memory leak in implementation
I am working on a project to implement infinite precision integers using char. All the functions work fine in giving the correct output, however there is a memory leak somewhere.
I am including my "addStringsInt" function along with the functions that it calls.
#include "integer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// ============== Start your code from here ==================

char* shift(char* ans, int shift){
    //need to return ans + index; 
    int A = getstrlen(ans);
    char* ans2 = new char[A+1 - shift];
    ans2[A-shift] = '\0';
    for (int i = shift; i < A; i++){
        ans2[i - shift] = ans[i]; 
    }
    return ans2; 
}

int getstrlen(const char* str){
    int counts = 0;
    //int counts0 = 0;
    //while (str[counts0] == '0'){
    //    if (str[counts0] == '\0') return 1;
    //    else counts0++;
    //}
    while (true){
        if (str[counts] == '\0') return counts; 
        counts++ ;
    }
}

bool isZero(const char* intA){
    int counts = 0; 
    while(true){
        if (intA[counts] == '\0') return true;
        else if (intA[counts] != '0' && intA[counts] != '-') return false;
        counts++;
    }
}

bool isEqualStringInt(const char* intA, const char* intB){
    if(isZero(intA) && isZero(intB)) return true;
    int counts = 0; 
    if (*intA == '-' && *intB == '-'){
        counts ++ ;
    }
    int countsA = 0;
    while (*intA == '0'){
        countsA++;
    }
    int countsB = 0;
    while (*intB == '0'){
        countsB++;
    }
    while (true){
        if (intA[counts + countsA] == '\0' && intB[counts+countsB] == '\0') return true; 
        else if (intA[counts + countsA] != intB[counts + countsB]) return false; 
        counts++; 
    }
}

char* flipSignStringInt(const char* intA){
    if (isZero(intA)){
        char* ans = new char[2]; 
        ans[0] = '0'; ans[1] = '\0';
        return ans;
    }
    int A = getstrlen(intA);
    if (intA[0] == '-'){
        char* ans = new char[A];
        ans[A-1] = '\0';
        for (int i =1; i < A; i++){
            ans[i-1] = intA[i];
        }
        return ans;
    }
    else {
        char* ans = new char[A+2];
        ans[A+1] = '\0';
        ans[0] = '-';
        for (int i =0; i < A; i++){
            ans[i+1] = intA[i];
        }
        return ans;
    }
}

bool isLargerThanStringInt(const char* intA, const char* intB){
    int indexA = 0; int indexB = 0; 
    if (isZero(intA)) return false; 
    if (*intA == '-'){
        if (*intB != '-') return false;
        indexA++;
        indexB++;
        //swap(intA, intB);
        const char* tem;
        tem = intB; 
        intB = intA;
        intA = tem; 
    }
    else if (*intB == '-') return true;
    while (intA[indexA] == '0'){
        indexA++;
        if (intA[indexA] == '\0'){
            indexA--;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (intB[indexB] == '0'){
        indexB++;
        if (intB[indexB] == '\0'){
            indexB--;
            break;
        }
    }
    int A = getstrlen(intA);
    int B = getstrlen(intB);
    if (A - indexA > B - indexB) return true;
    else if (A - indexA < B - indexB) return false;
    while (intA[indexA] != '\0'){
        if (intA[indexA] > intB[indexB]) return true;
        else if(intA[indexA] < intB[indexB]) return false;
        indexA++;
        indexB++;
        //if (intB[indexB] == '\0') return intA[indexA] != '\0';
    }
    return false;
}

char* mulPowerOfTenStringInt(const char* intA, int exp){
    int A = getstrlen(intA);
    if (isZero(intA) || A + exp <= 0){
        char* ans = new char[2];
        ans[0] = '0';
        ans[1] = '\0';
        return ans;
    }
    char* ans = new char[A + exp + 1]; 
    ans[A + exp] = '\0';
    //int end = min(A, A + exp);
    int end; 
    if (exp > 0) end = A;
    else end = A + exp; 
    for (int i =0; i < end; i++){
        ans[i] = intA[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i < exp; i++){
        ans[end + i] = '0';
    }
    return ans;
}

char* addStringInt(const char* intA, const char* intB){ 
    bool swapped = false;
    if (isLargerThanStringInt(intB, intA)){
        //swap(intA, intB);
        const char* tem;
        tem = intB; 
        intB = intA;
        intA = tem; 
        swapped = true; 
    }
    int A = getstrlen(intA);
    int B = getstrlen(intB);
    if (*intA == '-' || *intB != '-'){ //addition
        if (A < B){  //to make sure that A does not run out of digits before B
            //swap(intA, intB);
            const char* tem;
            tem = intB; 
            intB = intA;
            intA = tem; 
            //swap(A, B);
            int tem2;
            tem2 = B; 
            B = A;
            A = tem2; 
            swapped = !swapped ; //dont need it for addition, but whatever
        }
        char* ans = new char[A + 2];
        for (int i =0; i < A+1; i++) ans[i] = '0';
        //if (*intA == '-') *ans = *intA;
        bool BEnd = false;
        int carry = 0;
        ans[A+1] = '\0'; //ending before returning, answer is of size A+1 (in case we have a carry), for A+2nd element is the ending element; 
        for (int i =1; i <= A; i++){
            if (i == A){
                if (intA[0] == '-'){
                    if (carry){
                        ans[1] = '1';
                        ans[0] = '-';
                        return ans;
                    }
                    else{
                        ans[1] = '-'; //need to return ans + 1
                        char* ans2 = shift(ans, 1);
                        delete[] ans;
                        return ans2;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    carry += intA[0] -'0';
                    if (i <= B ) carry += intB[0] - '0';
                    ans[1] = '0' + (carry%10);
                    carry /= 10;
                    if (carry){
                        ans[0] = '1';
                        return ans;
                    }
                    else {
                        char* ans2 = shift(ans, 1);
                        delete[] ans;
                        return ans2;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i == B+1 || intB[B-i] == '-') BEnd = true; 
            if (BEnd){//B already finised, add function for carry
                carry += intA[A-i] - '0';
                ans[A+1-i] = '0' + (carry%10);
                carry /= 10;
            }
            else{
                int digitsum = (intA[A-i] - '0') + (intB[B-i] - '0') + carry;
                //cerr << "current digit sum for index " << i << " is " << digitsum << endl;
                ans[A+1-i] = '0' + (digitsum%10);
                carry = digitsum/10;
                //cerr << "carry left " << carry << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {//subtraction A - B ( where A,B > 0)
        swapped = false;
        char* flipped = flipSignStringInt(intB);
        if (isLargerThanStringInt(flipped, intA)){
            //swap(intA, intB);
            const char* tem;
            tem = intB; 
            intB = intA;
            intA = tem; 
            //swap(A, B);
            int tem2;
            tem2 = B; 
            B = A;
            A = tem2; 
            swapped = true; 
        }
        delete[] flipped;
        //////cerr << "intA: " << *intA << ", intB: " << *intB << " , swapped: " << swapped << endl;
        char* ans = new char[A+1];
        ans[A] = '\0';
        bool help = false; 
        bool BEnd = false; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= A; i++){
            if (i == A){
                int index = 0;
                if (intA[0] != '-'){
                    if (i <= B && intB[B-i] != '-') ans[0] = '0' + (intA[0] - intB[B-i] - help);
                    else  ans[0] = intA[0] - help;
                    //cerr << "ans[1] = " << ans[1] << endl;
                }
                else ans[0] = '-';
                while (true && index < A - 1){
                    if (ans[index] != '0' && ans[index] != '-'){
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                if (swapped){
                    index--;
                    ans[index] = '-';
                }
                //cerr << "index " << index << endl;
                //need to return ans + index; 
                char* ans2 = shift(ans, index);
                delete[] ans;
                return ans2; 
            }
            if (i == B+1 || intB[B-i] == '-'){
                BEnd = true; 
            }
            if (BEnd){
                if (help){
                    if (intA[A-i] == '0'){
                        ans[A-i] = '9';
                    }
                    else {
                        ans[A-i] = intA[A-i] - 1;
                        help = 0;}
                }
                else ans[A-i] = intA[A-i];
            }
            else{
                if (intA[A-i] - help >= intB[B-i]){
                    ans[A-i] = '0' + (intA[A-i] - help - intB[B-i]);
                    help = 0;
                }
                else{
                    ans[A-i] = '0' + (10 + intA[A-i] - help - intB[B-i]);
                    help = 1; 
                }
                //cerr << "ans[A-i] " << ans[A-i] << ", help " << help << endl;
            }
            //cerr << "at iteration " << i << " , digit of answer is " << ans[A+1-i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

result from fsanitzie
I am really stumped at what the issue could be, appreciate any and all help.
What I have tried:
I have tried tracing each new array I make to make sure it is either deleted or returned.
I have also tried using fsanitize, however that just tells me that there is some leak in "addStringsInt" function.
From other posts, it seems valgrind is a good tool to use here, however I am not using Linux.
I am expecting to remove any memory leak within the "addStringsInt" function.

You look like to study C with new/delete/cout/cerr. Stop using raw pointers, use std::vector.

Unfortunately, for this I am not allowed to use vector and I have to work with raw pointers.

What's inside integer.h?

integer.h is just the header file that declares these functions to be used in main.cpp file.

Who doesn't allow that you? Send them this link Stop teaching C!

You need to analyse every possible code path to ensure that EVERY executed new expression is matched exactly once by a corresponding delete expression.  That won't be simple for your code, as there is a lot conditional logic and looping, but there is no magic wand to avoid the analysis.  If you want to simplify the analysis, then simplify the code logic. For example, write your own helper struct/class type(s) that uses a RAII approach  (i.e. constructors do new, destructors do corresponding delete, any member functions that resize ensure they clean up correctly before returning).

Could you add main() body from main.cpp to the question? Your trace shows it is the function to blame, not addStringInt().

Why's the manual memory management? Required readings for you: std::vector, RAII, rule 350. If there's a leak or use after free, you have definitely violated rule 350.

You can feed your program here to demo memory leak.

"to implement infinite precision integers" -- Not possible. Perhaps you mean arbitrary precision integers?

"that just tells me that there is some leak in 'addStringsInt' function" -- That's progress (although your code calls it addStringInt, not addStringsInt). Next, drop your belief that this function is supposed to add something. Focus on one example input that demonstrates the leak. For this input, does *intA == '-' || *intB != '-' hold? Whatever the answer, it looks like about half the function could be dropped. Keep eliminating suspect code until you have a culprit.

@Momin for this I am not allowed to use vector -- The std::vector class has been officially part of C++ for 26 years now.  Who is giving these ridiculous requirements that you are not allowed to use std::vector?  If the goal is to create an arbitrary precision class, that goal is stopped all due to writing code to attempt to maintain new and delete.

Main problem is you are using coding patterns form C++03/C++98 and some bad practices repeated in lots of courses.
C++11 nowadays is absolute minimum.
Basically explicit use of operators new and delete should be avoided (in practice rarely use in libraries by adverseness developers).
You should rewrite your program to use:

std::string (which are available before C++98)
std::vector (which are available before C++98)
std::unique_ptr
std::shared_ptr

This way RAII pattern will take over memory management and you will resolve 95% of memory leaks. Including your current leak.
Also names of your functions are confusing. For example shift actually drops a prefix. Note that with invalid input your program can crash (getstrlen(ans) < shift).

How to identify a leak
On the screenshot you've provided, it tells you which sequence of calls is to blame:

#0: operator new[] - asan_new_delete.cpp:98
#1: shift(char*, int) - integer.cpp:9
#2: addStringInt(char const*, char const*) - integer.cpp:208
#3: main() - main.cpp:13

How do you read this? The memory leak was allocated in shift()
    int A = getstrlen(ans);
    char* ans2 = new char[A+1 - shift]; //line 9
    //...
    return ans2; //memory ownership passed to the caller

In cases like these, the function assumes the caller knows it received a pointer to dynamically-allocated memory and will call delete[] on it eventually.
The caller was addStringInt() (it would be better if you highlighted line 208 yourself in the question)
                    else {
                        char* ans2 = shift(ans, 1); //line 208
                        delete[] ans;
                        return ans2;
                    }


Once again, the function here passes responsibility for freeing the memory further up. Now main() received the pointer and should invoke delete[] on it. Alas, we're not given its code but apparently it forgot to do so.
How to prevent this from happening
While other answers and comments already told to use standard containers thus removing any necessity for explicit new[]/delete[] calls (and yes, it's a good advice), there is one class in particular that allows to explicitly distinguish between "a pointer to some memory owned by another object" and "a pointer to a memory owned by whoever has this pointer". C++11 gives us
std::unique_ptr / std::unique_ptr<T[]>
With it, you can explicitly mark functions as "returning a memory-owning pointer":
std::unique_ptr<char[]> shift(char* ans, int shift){
    //need to return ans + index; 
    int A = getstrlen(ans);
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ans2(new char[A+1 - shift]);
    ans2[A-shift] = '\0';
    for (int i = shift; i < A; i++){
        ans2[i - shift] = ans[i]; 
    }
    return ans2;
}

Now, no matter who calls shift(), they will know just from the signature that:

ans is passed as a non-owning pointer and will not be delete[]ed;
return value is an owning pointer.

It may not seem much when the function body is seven lines but much less obvious for addStringInt which is 150+ lines long.
Furthermore, now delete[] will be invoked by the compiler whenever the owning variable ceases to exist, eliminating chances of a caller forgetting to free the memory. Also, if a function returns an owning pointer in some cases and a non-owning pointer in others, the compiler would detect that error for you.
